# Can this be done?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I recently came into an issue in regards to my course schedule. I talked to one of the professors in the math department and suggested I not take 3 science classes as well as math 295 (hardest math sequence my school has to offer). This puts me at issue in regards to meeting the math requirements for my physics classes. I then thought maybe testing out will be a creative solution. My question is whether or not it would be likely that I go through the Spivak Calculus book and Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra all the while actually understanding the material. I have approximately 4 months to do this (over summer break) before I am issued a test out exam out of math 295 and 296. The topics covered in these book are calculus 1,2,3, and linear algebra (theory based).I have had experience in these topics but only in terms of computing problems (Stewart calculus).

Comment: I don't know about the Hoffman-Kunze book, but Spivak will require some real dedication to pull it off in that time even if it was without the linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

You should talk to other students or, preferably, professors at your school, about this. They'll know more about this 295 course than most people on Math.SE and so you'd get better answers from them. Good luck!

It's definitely possible to read textbooks and test out of classes, but you know more about your work ethic, how well you learn from reading books, etc.